# How to see revenue-per-page in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

This seems like it should be really simple to figure out.  What I want to see how much revenue was generated by people who visited any page.  That is to say, how many people viewed the page `/foo` and then later went on to make a purchase?  And how much did these folk spend?

I cannot, for the life of me, find a way to generate that data.  I can see this data per landing page, by creating a report with the dimension "Landing Page" and the metric "Revenue":

**My report config:**
[image]

**My report output**
[image]

That works just fine.  But I don't care about how people entered, I care about all the pages they visited, whether those were entrance pages or not.  So when I simply change the dimension from "Landing Page" to just "Page" I get this:

**My New Report Config**
[image]

**My New Report Output**[image]

*Why is it zero?*  Shouldn't revenue be applied to any page that was visited in the lead up to a purchase?  We can see there's lots of revenue, so how is this report showing no revenue?

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you want is the "Page Value" metric. More info [here](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2012/07/understanding-and-using-page-value.html)

In your report, you would only see rows and data for pages where an actual transaction (or a goal with a value) take place, which according to your description, is not what you want.

Comment: I'm willing to concede that what I want may not be possible, but my real question is _why_ is it not possible, and I am certain that this explanation is not correct.  For one, if the page-by-revenue report were limited to pages where actual transactions occurred, I should still see _some_ pages, not a completely empty report.  Second, I can see revenue in several contexts that are not directly tied to transactions.  For instance, I can see revenue per event (http://i.imgur.com/o2AkdNa.png), and revenue per landing page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdYpE.png).

Comment: The reason you see revenue associated with landing pages is because the scope of the landing page dimension is "session" scope. Therefore, in this context, revenue makes sense as this is showing you the revenue that was generated by sessions that landed on this page. The reason you're seeing revenue associated with events is most likely because you're associating enhanced ecommerce revenue with these specific events. I agree with you that you should not see a completely empty report when creating a report of Page vs. Revenue. To troubleshoot this, I would need more information.